# Not able to show/hide div which is nearest to checkbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using Ruby on Rails with Cocoon Gem to generate dynamic form. Using form User can add/remove their Education details.

My form looks like this:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_to, :edit_education_path %>
        <%= f.label :institution_name, 'Institution Name'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.text_field :institution_name, placeholder: 'Enter Institution Name ', class: 'form-control', required: true %>
          <i class="theme-cl ti-home"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :course_name, 'Course Name'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.text_field :course_name, placeholder: 'Enter Course Name', class: 'form-control', required: true %>
          <i class="theme-cl ti-mobile"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :course_completed, 'Course Complete'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.check_box :course_completed, class: 'form-control checkbox' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 finished_year'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :finished_year, 'Finished Year (optional)'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.select :finished_year, WorkExperiencesHelper.years, { prompt: '-- Select --' }, class: 'form-control' %>
          <i class="theme-cl ti-mobile"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row expected_finished_time'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :expected_finished_month, 'Expected Finished Month (optional)'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.select :expected_finished_month, WorkExperiencesHelper.months, { prompt: '-- Select --' }, class: 'form-control' %>
          <i class="theme-cl ti-mobile"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :expected_finished_year, 'Expected Finished Year (optional)'  %>
        <div class="input-with-icon">
          <%= f.select :expected_finished_year, WorkExperiencesHelper.years, { prompt: '-- Select --' }, class: 'form-control' %>
          <i class="theme-cl ti-mobile"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :course_highlights, 'Course Highlights (optional)' %>
        <%= f.text_area :course_highlights, rows: 10, placeholder: 'Add activities, projects, awards or achievements during your study.', class: 'form-control'  %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= link_to_remove_association  f, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expected_finished_time").hide();
    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".expected_finished_time").hide();
        $(".finished_year").show();
      } else {
        $(".expected_finished_time").show();
        $(".finished_year").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

By default checkbox is checked. What I want to obtain is when user uncheck the checkbox then closest div with class `.finished_year` should be hidden and closest div with class `.expected_finished_year` should be shown to user. With my current code all div with class `.finished_year` is getting hidden. But I want only the closest div to checkbox to be hidden. My Jquery looks like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expected_finished_time").hide();
    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".expected_finished_time").hide();
        $(".finished_year").show();
      } else {
        $(".expected_finished_time").show();
        $(".finished_year").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have tried using `(this).parent().closest('.finished_year').hide()` but this is also not working. Cocoon Gem allows to add multiple Education details at once. So at any given time there could be multiple check boxes in the form. When user check/uncheck the checkbox I want the closest div to hide/show.

Comment: `closest` is in fact `closest-parent`, won't look up for `sibling`

Comment: @ProGu ok so how my jquery should look like? any hints ?

Comment: `closest('.row').find('.finished_year') ` or `closest('.row').next('.expected_finished_time')`, something like that

Comment: @ProGu your suggestion worked. Please write it as answer so that I can accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Please next time post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post ONLY HTML, JS and CSS. This is NOT a ruby-on-rails problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you toggle after finding the correct parent

```js
$(function() {
  $(".expected_finished_time").hide();
  $(".checkbox").on("click", function() {
    const $row = $(this).closest(".row");
    const chk = this.checked;
    $(".expected_finished_time", $row).toggle(!chk)
    $(".finished_year", $row).toggle(chk)
  });
});
`
```